# Pass a structure to a C dll from C# and get the structure values assigned?

Tags: c#, dll

My C code for dll creation is

```
  typedef struct st_struct{
     unsigned char a;
     unsigned char b;
   } st_struct;

  __declspec(dllexport) void  __stdcall ftn(st_struct *s )
{
     s->a =10;
     s->b =20;
```

}

My C # code code is as follows

```
namespace check_ex
{
    [Serializable]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class st_struct
    {
        public byte a;
        public byte b;
    };

[DllImport("exMydll.dll")]
public static extern void ftn(st_struct inputs); 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        st_struct x = new st_struct();
        ftn(x);
        Console.Write(x.a, x.b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Correction : It is public struct st_struct { public byte a; public byte b; };

Comment: Hi Lakshmi, welcome to SO. What is the difficulty that you are facing with this code? care to include the details and ask your question as well

Comment: I am not getting the values in the structure object in C#. Why?